# Why did this character appear this way in WandaVision?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

There's another question on this site about why Wanda "recognized" Fietro as her brother, since he doesn't look like MCU Quicksilver at all.  ([How did Wanda recognize this character?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244415/how-did-wanda-recognize-this-character))  The answer is a bit weird, but it technically works - Wanda wanted to believe that her brother was back, and he established himself as being her brother when he first appeared.

But we know that Agatha was the one who brought Pietro "back," not Wanda.  Agatha used him as a spy to learn more information about Wanda under the guise of her long-dead brother.

But is there a reason why she chose Fietro?  Did she just make up a random person and have him pretend like he's Pietro?  It makes even less sense from Agatha's perspective, as Wanda has no real reason to accept this stranger as her brother, but it somehow works.

Given that horrible "Bohner" reveal at the season's end, it does seem that Fietro/Ralph is just a random person whom Agatha kidnapped and controlled.  But is there any reason for why she chose him specifically for this?

Comment: Isn't her brother's name "Pietro"?

Comment: It's possible that Agatha was seeing the cracks show in Wanda's mental stability and chose to risk this reveal on the hopes that Wanda is in fact _that desperate_ to believe it's her real brother.

Comment: @NomadMaker Yeah, that's her brother's name, but when Agatha reveals everything to Wanda she calls him "Fietro" (fake Pietro) and then it's revealed that his real name is Ralph, which is why I jumped between using those names

Comment: @Möoz Honestly, given the explanation for why Wanda accepted Fietro as her brother, this is probably the most likely explanation - but what a risk it was.

Comment: the better question is why they chose an actor to deliberately trick a particular subset of knowledgable viewers (those that would recognize the actor as playing the same character in a different film universe)

Comment: @NKCampbell And they wonder why we thought there'd be a Multiverse in the finale

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ralph Bohner owned the plot of land next door to the plot that Vision bought for him and Wanda, the one Wanda constructs with magic and lives in inside Westview. This is brought to our attention when Ralph is holding Monica hostage in the finale:

> **Monica:** Agnes doesn't live here. You do.
>
> **Fietro:** Oh.
>
> **Monica:** You're Ralph Bohner?
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 9, "The Series Finale"</sub>

Presumably she chose him so she can be Wanda's neighbour and so have an excuse to get close to her. For what it's worth we have several hints at this early on, Agnes refers to a her "husband" as Ralph throughout the opening episodes even though he's never seen.

> **Agnes:** Oh, how marvelous! How many years?
>
> **Wanda:** Well, it feels like we've always been together.
>
> **Agnes:** Lucky gal. The only way Ralph would remember our anniversary is if there was a beer named June 2nd.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 1, "Filmed Before a Live Studio Audience"</sub>

---

FWIW Ralph lives at 2804 Sherwood Drive, Westview, NJ 08801 and Wanda/The Vision's place is at 2800 Sherwood Drive, Westview, NJ 08801. We see this when Monica finds Ralph's water bill and Wanda opens the house deeds respectively. (Sorry for the poor blurry picture but I couldn't get it to pause on a decent one).

[image: Close up on the water bill as Monica reads it to see Ralph is the owner] [image: Close up on the house deeds over Wanda's shoulder as she reads Vision's note on them]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer!  The screenshots are great.